# Likewise 6.1 breaks network on Ubuntu 10.04.3

Tags: ifconfig, likewise

I'm trying to use PowerBroker LikeWise 6.1 on Ubuntu LTS 10.04.3 to join to my AD domain.  I've done this in the past before LikeWise was owned by PowerBroker & I can get it to work "pretty well".  However, each time I try to install this version, it breaks my network connection.  I'm not sure why or where to look to fix it.  Any suggestions on where to look?  I've checked some of the usual network config files Likewise modifies:

- /etc/resolv.conf
- /etc/hosts
- /etc/nsswitch.conf

They all seem to be OK with respect to the network I'm on.  `ifconfig` shows inet6 for eth0 but not inet (it should show inet)

> eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:1c:75:be
>             inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe1c:75be/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:3159 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:255179 (255.1 KB)  TX bytes:936 (936.0 B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that Apparmor doesn't like the additional stuff Likewise adds to /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient3 file.  Only solution I've been able to find is disabling Apparmor for dhclient3:

```
# ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient3 /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
```

then

```
# apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/sbin.dhclient3
```